# What chemicals would make lime sulfur dip to produce a green colored smoke?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, safety

I work at an animal shelter that uses lime sulfur dip to treat ringworm. We had an accident where someone mixed bleach instead of water with the lime sulfur dip which caused us to go through decontamination with Hazmat. Are there any other chemicals or acids that could cause this to happen?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, mixing lime sulfur (calcium polysulfide) with an acid will react via the following reaction:

$$\ce{S^{2-}\:(aq) +2H+\:(aq) ->H2S\:(g)}$$

Which is both extremely toxic and extremely flammable. You should always be extremely cautious and mindful when mixing any chemicals and always be sure to label everything!